# Can't remove element from collection in OneToMany side

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing online store app and I'm struggling with purchase system. Generally I need to write service which works with steps:

- Check whether customer has sufficient funds for payment
- If he does - subtract amount of product's cost from `Customer`'s balance
- Delete `Product` from `Customer` collection (this doesn't work!)
- Save `Customer` with updated collection to database
- Delete `Product` from database

However, no matter how I try to do this, `Product` is not deleted from `Customer` collection. `remove()` method, `clear()` method, etc., nothing works. Every time I log `Customer` collection to console after purchase, purchased `Product` still belongs to `Customer` who posted `Product`. This major problem causes many bugs which - for example - regard saving `Customer` with non-existing `Product` (since in next purchase, saving `Customer` includes non-deleted previous `Product` in `Customer` collection).

Snippets of code:

Piece of Service:

```
public boolean processPayment(Customer customerToEdit, Product productToOperate) {
        if (customerToEdit.getBalance() >= productToOperate.getProductCost())
        {
            Customer retrievedProductOwner = productToOperate.getProductOwner();
            customerToEdit.setBalance(customerToEdit.getBalance()-productToOperate.getProductCost());
/* This doesn't execute! */
            retrievedProductOwner.getOwnedProducts().remove(productToOperate);
            customerDAO.save(retrievedProductOwner);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Insufficient funds!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Piece of Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/showOffer")
    public String getOffer(@RequestParam("offerId") int offerId, Model theModel, @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails user) {
        Product retrievedProduct = productService.findById(offerId);
        if (customerService.processPayment(user.getCustomer(), retrievedProduct)) {
            productService.delete(retrievedProduct.getId());
        }
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

Product.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String productName;
    
    @Column(name="description")
    private String productDescription;
    
    @Column(name="category")
    private String productCategory;
    
    @Column(name="cost")
    private int productCost;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
    private Customer productOwner;
/* (...) */
```

Customer.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    //Class fields
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="balance")
    private int balance;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="productOwner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Product> ownedProducts;
/* (...) */
```

Comment: check CascadeType options it may help https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types to reduce code and change on one entity will be propagated to child with @ManyToOne - DETACH

Comment: Applying CascadeType to either ManyToOne or OneToMany with DETACH doesn't change anything unfortunately. Problem still occurs. Despite ```Product``` being correctly deleted from database, it does not detach itself from ```Customer``` collection.

Comment: Everythink is in the documentation - maybe I have mistaken the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable orphan removal of products by adding CascadeType.PERSIST and orphan removal true

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "productOwner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Product> ownedProducts = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you save the customer this should trigger delete of the removed Product